# How to Use LOAD DATA to import JSON data and specify date data type on import

Tags: mysql, json

I'm importing JSON data in sql and would like like to convert human readable date data to yyyy-mm-dd format.

Here's the flow:

I'm using the following json file stored under `/home/name/json_data/sample.json`

```
{
    "price": null,
    "sale_list": [
        {
            "buyer": "SmackMe089",
            "date": "April 29th 2019 21:20:50",
            "id": "1234",
            "item_desc": ""
        }
}
```

Create the table in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
         id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         json_data JSON NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Loading the file into mysql:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/name/json_data/sample.json' INTO TABLE example_table (json_data);
```

When loading data into the table is possible convert the date data to yyyy-mm-dd? On querying I am able to assign data types to the columns, but not sure how to properly convert date data. Can this be done during querying or during import?

EX:

```
select test.* from example_table,
JSON_TABLE(json_data, '$.sale_list[*]' COLUMNS (
buyer VARCHAR(40) PATH '$.buyer',
date VARCHAR(40) PATH '$.date',
id VARCHAR(40) PATH '$.id',
item_desc VARCHAR(40) PATH '$.item_desc'
) ) test;
```